# Вывод данных из базы

Tags: sql

Есть две базы `order` и `customer` хочу получить количество заказов конкретного `customer`

```
SELECT  o.firstname, c.firstname  
FROM o.order 
INNER JOIN c.customer ON c.customer_id=o.customer_id
```

Дублирует `customer` как сделать что бы `customer` выводился один раз и у него стояло количество заказов?

Comment: количество дает функция `count(*)` что бы было в разрезе кустомеров нужен `group by c.firstname, c.customer_id` и конечно o.firstname выводить в таком запросе видимо безполено, потому что их может быть несколько для одного кустомера

Answer (score 0):

Добавить группировку в конце запроса и функцию агрегации вначале (+ можно чуть-чуть упростить ON):

```
SELECT c.firstname, COUNT(*) AS num
FROM o.order INNER JOIN 
     c.customer USING(customer_id)
GROUP BY c.customer_id
```